# How could I open a ssh shell to remote with Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible

I am migrating from Capistrano to Ansible for deploying web application. I managed to migrate almost all our recipes but I am stuck with one.

To quickly access a remote server we used to hit `cap production ssh`, this command execute a local ssh command with the stage configuration. That way anybody in the team can access the remote server quickly without having to find the username and hostname needed.

I a trying to do the same thing with Ansible but I not sure it is even possible. All I get so far is this error: `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Here is the Ansible task I use.

```
- name: SSH to host
  hosts: app
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - command: ssh {{ ansible_user }}@{{ inventory_hostname }}
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. 
Why would you use a command to execute ssh from a playbook with no task to accomplish?

Comment: I want a command that open a remote shell using the ansible inventory informations.

I know it is not what Ansible is supposed to do. It is not what capistrano is supposed to do neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ansible is definitely not designed to do that.
I's not possible to open an interactive SSH connection with a playbook.

A possible solution to your need is to extract SSH information from the inventory using [`ansible-inventory`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ansible-inventory.html) with something like that:

```
eval $(ansible-inventory --inventory ${INVENTORY_FILE_PATH} --host ${INVENTORY_HOSTNAME} | jq -r '"ssh -p " + (.ansible_port|tostring) + " " + .ansible_user + "@" + .ansible_host')
```

I let you find a way to handle the cases when there is no specified port (an so fallback to port `22`) or when there is a `ansible_ssh_private_key_file` to use with `-i` option.

Comment: ansible_ssh_pass will require `sshpass -p x ssh ...`